# In VSCode how to stick the explorer to the sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode i'd like to make the explorer view always visible even when other sidebar windows are open. Is there an extension or setting that I can change to achieve such behaivour?

I've tried to find extensions or setting but I could not found any.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not possible in VS Code.

Several people have made feature requests, e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26777, which you could upvote.